# Отображение изображений согласно выбранной строке в QComboBox

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, qt-designer, qcombobox

Необходимо отобразить изображение согласно выбранной строке в `QComboBox`. 
Добавил код взаимодействия, стал появляться просто серый экран.

Что должно быть прикрепляю на изображениях:

[image: КАРТИНКА 1]

[image: КАРТИНКА 2]

---

**main.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(1148, 589)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(840, 0, 341, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:1 rgba(255, 0, 0, 245))")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-10, 0, 1161, 591))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: qconicalgradient(cx:0.5, cy:0.5, angle:134.2, stop:0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 245), stop:0.619318 rgba(0, 0, 255, 232));")
        self.label_2.setText("")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.spinBox_2 = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(Form)
        self.spinBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 540, 71, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(36)
        self.spinBox_2.setFont(font)
        self.spinBox_2.setStyleSheet("\n"
"font: 36pt \"GOST type B\";\n"
"color:#fff;\n"
"background-color:rgb(0, 0, 255);")
        self.spinBox_2.setObjectName("spinBox_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 0, 411, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:1 rgba(255, 0, 0, 245))")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 500, 481, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("\n"
"font: 20pt \"GOST type B\";\n"
"color:#fff;\n"
"background-color:rgb(0, 0, 255);")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Form)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(850, 30, 291, 41))
        self.comboBox.addItem("Тип ")
        self.comboBox.addItem("Тип")
        self.comboBox.addItem("С о")
        self.comboBox.addItem("С ")
        self.comboBox.addItem("Ти")
        self.comboBox.addItem("Т")
        self.comboBox.addItem("С")
        self.comboBox.addItem("Б")
        self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.update_image)  # Connect the signal to update_image
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.comboBox.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox.setStyleSheet("background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:1 rgba(255, 0, 0, 245))")
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.spinBox_3 = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(Form)
        self.spinBox_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 30, 71, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(36)
        self.spinBox_3.setFont(font)
        self.spinBox_3.setStyleSheet("background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:1 rgba(255, 0, 0, 245))")
        self.spinBox_3.setObjectName("spinBox_3")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 110, 291, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setStyleSheet("\n"
"font: 18pt \"GOST type B\";\n"
"color:#fff;\n"
"background-color:rgb(0, 0, 255);")
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.lineEdit_11 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 150, 81, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.lineEdit_11.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_11.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.lineEdit_11.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.lineEdit_11.setStyleSheet("\n"
"font: 18pt \"GOST type B\";\n"
"color:#fff;\n"
"background-color:rgb(0, 0, 255);")
        self.lineEdit_11.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_11.setObjectName("lineEdit_11")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 411, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_7.setFont(font)
        self.label_7.setStyleSheet("background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:1 rgba(255, 0, 0, 245))")
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.lineEdit_12 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 40, 81, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST Type BU")
        font.setPointSize(28)
        self.lineEdit_12.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_12.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.lineEdit_12.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.lineEdit_12.setStyleSheet("background:qconicalgradient(cx:0.5, cy:0.5, angle:315.3, stop:0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 255), stop:1 rgba(0, 0, 255, 255))")
        self.lineEdit_12.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_12.setObjectName("lineEdit_12")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 220, 411, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_8.setFont(font)
        self.label_8.setStyleSheet("\n"
"font: 18pt \"GOST type B\";\n"
"color:#fff;\n"
"background-color:rgb(0, 0, 255);")
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.lineEdit_13 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_13.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 260, 81, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.lineEdit_13.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_13.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.lineEdit_13.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.lineEdit_13.setStyleSheet("\n"
"font: 18pt \"GOST type B\";\n"
"color:#fff;\n"
"background-color:rgb(0, 0, 255);")
        self.lineEdit_13.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_13.setObjectName("lineEdit_13")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 330, 521, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_9.setFont(font)
        self.label_9.setStyleSheet("\n"
"font: 18pt \"GOST type B\";\n"
"color:#fff;\n"
"background-color:rgb(0, 0, 255);")
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.lineEdit_14 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_14.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 370, 81, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.lineEdit_14.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_14.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.lineEdit_14.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.lineEdit_14.setStyleSheet("\n"
"font: 18pt \"GOST type B\";\n"
"color:#fff;\n"
"background-color:rgb(0, 0, 255);")
        self.lineEdit_14.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_14.setObjectName("lineEdit_14")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 440, 611, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_10.setFont(font)
        self.label_10.setStyleSheet("\n"
"font: 18pt \"GOST type B\";\n"
"color:#fff;\n"
"background-color:rgb(0, 0, 255);")
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.lineEdit_15 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_15.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 480, 81, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.lineEdit_15.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_15.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.lineEdit_15.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.lineEdit_15.setStyleSheet("\n"
"font: 18pt \"GOST type B\";\n"
"color:#fff;\n"
"background-color:rgb(0, 0, 255);")
        self.lineEdit_15.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_15.setObjectName("lineEdit_15")
        self.label_2.raise_()
        self.label.raise_()
        self.spinBox_2.raise_()
        self.label_3.raise_()
        self.label_4.raise_()
        self.comboBox.raise_()
        self.spinBox_3.raise_()
        self.label_6.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_11.raise_()
        self.label_7.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_12.raise_()
        self.label_8.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_13.raise_()
        self.label_9.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_14.raise_()
        self.label_10.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_15.raise_()

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "ВЫБЕРИТЕ ТИП :"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form", "Укажите количество человек Д:"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Form", "Укажите количество человек о:"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("Form", "Тип "))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("Form", "Тип"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("Form", "С о"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("Form", "С "))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(4, _translate("Form", "Ти"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(5, _translate("Form", "Т"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(6, _translate("Form", "С"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(7, _translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("Form", "Вероятность отхода равна:"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("Form", "Эффективность 2  "))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("Form", "Эффективность"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("Form", "Вероятность работоспособности машин охранения"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("Form", "Вероятность продолжения марша колонны после нападения"))

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(800, 600)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Form)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(850, 30, 291, 41))
        self.comboBox.addItem("Тип ")
        self.comboBox.addItem("Тип")
        self.comboBox.addItem("С о")
        self.comboBox.addItem("С ")
        self.comboBox.addItem("Ти")
        self.comboBox.addItem("Т")
        self.comboBox.addItem("С")
        self.comboBox.addItem("Б")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 20, 400, 300))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))

    def update_image(self, index):
        image_path = ""
        if index == 0:
            image_path = "L.png"
        elif index == 1:
            image_path = "V.png"
        elif index == 2:
            image_path = "M.png"

        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(image_path)
        scaled_pixmap = pixmap.scaled(400, 300, QtCore.Qt.AspectRatioMode.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.label_2.setPixmap(scaled_pixmap)
        self.label_2.setScaledContents(True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    ui.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(ui.update_image)  # Connect the signal to update_image
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: за капслок сразу минус и голос за закрытие, не читая вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(1148, 589)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(840, 0, 341, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:1 rgba(255, 0, 0, 245))")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-10, 0, 1161, 591))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: qconicalgradient(cx:0.5, cy:0.5, angle:134.2, stop:0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 245), stop:0.619318 rgba(0, 0, 255, 232));")
        self.label_2.setText("")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.spinBox_2 = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(Form)
        self.spinBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 540, 71, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(36)
        self.spinBox_2.setFont(font)
        self.spinBox_2.setStyleSheet("\n"
"font: 36pt \"GOST type B\";\n"
"color:#fff;\n"
"background-color:rgb(0, 0, 255);")
        self.spinBox_2.setObjectName("spinBox_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 0, 411, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:1 rgba(255, 0, 0, 245))")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 500, 481, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("\n"
"font: 20pt \"GOST type B\";\n"
"color:#fff;\n"
"background-color:rgb(0, 0, 255);")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Form)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(850, 30, 291, 41))
        self.comboBox.addItem("Тип ")
        self.comboBox.addItem("Тип")
        self.comboBox.addItem("С о")
        self.comboBox.addItem("С ")
        self.comboBox.addItem("Ти")
        self.comboBox.addItem("Т")
        self.comboBox.addItem("С")
        self.comboBox.addItem("Б")

#        self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.update_image)  
        # Connect the signal to update_image

        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.comboBox.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox.setStyleSheet("background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:1 rgba(255, 0, 0, 245))")
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.spinBox_3 = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(Form)
        self.spinBox_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 30, 71, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(36)
        self.spinBox_3.setFont(font)
        self.spinBox_3.setStyleSheet("background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:1 rgba(255, 0, 0, 245))")
        self.spinBox_3.setObjectName("spinBox_3")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 110, 291, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setStyleSheet("\n"
"font: 18pt \"GOST type B\";\n"
"color:#fff;\n"
"background-color:rgb(0, 0, 255);")
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.lineEdit_11 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 150, 81, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.lineEdit_11.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_11.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.lineEdit_11.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.lineEdit_11.setStyleSheet("\n"
"font: 18pt \"GOST type B\";\n"
"color:#fff;\n"
"background-color:rgb(0, 0, 255);")
        self.lineEdit_11.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_11.setObjectName("lineEdit_11")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 411, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_7.setFont(font)
        self.label_7.setStyleSheet("background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:1 rgba(255, 0, 0, 245))")
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.lineEdit_12 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 40, 81, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST Type BU")
        font.setPointSize(28)
        self.lineEdit_12.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_12.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.lineEdit_12.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.lineEdit_12.setStyleSheet("background:qconicalgradient(cx:0.5, cy:0.5, angle:315.3, stop:0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 255), stop:1 rgba(0, 0, 255, 255))")
        self.lineEdit_12.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_12.setObjectName("lineEdit_12")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 220, 411, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_8.setFont(font)
        self.label_8.setStyleSheet("\n"
"font: 18pt \"GOST type B\";\n"
"color:#fff;\n"
"background-color:rgb(0, 0, 255);")
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.lineEdit_13 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_13.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 260, 81, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.lineEdit_13.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_13.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.lineEdit_13.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.lineEdit_13.setStyleSheet("\n"
"font: 18pt \"GOST type B\";\n"
"color:#fff;\n"
"background-color:rgb(0, 0, 255);")
        self.lineEdit_13.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_13.setObjectName("lineEdit_13")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 330, 521, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_9.setFont(font)
        self.label_9.setStyleSheet("\n"
"font: 18pt \"GOST type B\";\n"
"color:#fff;\n"
"background-color:rgb(0, 0, 255);")
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.lineEdit_14 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_14.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 370, 81, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.lineEdit_14.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_14.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.lineEdit_14.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.lineEdit_14.setStyleSheet("\n"
"font: 18pt \"GOST type B\";\n"
"color:#fff;\n"
"background-color:rgb(0, 0, 255);")
        self.lineEdit_14.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_14.setObjectName("lineEdit_14")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 440, 611, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_10.setFont(font)
        self.label_10.setStyleSheet("\n"
"font: 18pt \"GOST type B\";\n"
"color:#fff;\n"
"background-color:rgb(0, 0, 255);")
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.lineEdit_15 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_15.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 480, 81, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("GOST type B")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.lineEdit_15.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_15.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.lineEdit_15.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.lineEdit_15.setStyleSheet("\n"
"font: 18pt \"GOST type B\";\n"
"color:#fff;\n"
"background-color:rgb(0, 0, 255);")
        self.lineEdit_15.setText("")
        self.lineEdit_15.setObjectName("lineEdit_15")
        self.label_2.raise_()
        self.label.raise_()
        self.spinBox_2.raise_()
        self.label_3.raise_()
        self.label_4.raise_()
        self.comboBox.raise_()
        self.spinBox_3.raise_()
        self.label_6.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_11.raise_()
        self.label_7.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_12.raise_()
        self.label_8.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_13.raise_()
        self.label_9.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_14.raise_()
        self.label_10.raise_()
        self.lineEdit_15.raise_()

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "ВЫБЕРИТЕ ТИП :"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form", "Укажите количество человек Д:"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Form", "Укажите количество человек о:"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("Form", "Тип "))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("Form", "Тип"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("Form", "С о"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("Form", "С "))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(4, _translate("Form", "Ти"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(5, _translate("Form", "Т"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(6, _translate("Form", "С"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(7, _translate("Form", "Б"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("Form", "Вероятность отхода равна:"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("Form", "Эффективность 2  "))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("Form", "Эффективность"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("Form", "Вероятность работоспособности машин охранения"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("Form", "Вероятность продолжения марша колонны после нападения"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):                          # +++
    def __init__(self):                                                # +++
        super().__init__()                                             # +++
        
        self.setupUi(self)                                             # +++
        
        self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.update_image)   # +++ 
        
    def update_image(self, index):
        #print(f'index = {index}') 
        image_path = ""
        if index == 0:
            image_path = "Ok.png"
        elif index == 1:
            image_path = "boy33.png"
        elif index == 2:
            image_path = "lena2.png"
            
        else:                                    # +++ а что если другой index ???
            return                               # +++

        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(image_path)
        scaled_pixmap = pixmap.scaled(400, 300, 
            QtCore.Qt.AspectRatioMode.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.label_2.setPixmap(scaled_pixmap)
        self.label_2.setScaledContents(True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
#    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
#    ui = Ui_Form()
#    ui.setupUi(Form)
#    ui.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(ui.update_image)  
#    Form.show()

    w = MainWindow()                                           # +++
    w.show()                                                   # +++
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо,@S. Nick!размер еще поправлю картинки и все ок

Comment: @GomerSimson пожалуйста.    Будут проблемы - зададите новый вопрос.